# Select different results from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table used to gather evaluations from users, its structure is really basic and defined below along with some example rows:

```
id_user | id_affirmation | isCorrect
------------------------------------
   1    |       10       |   true
   1    |       13       |   false
   2    |       23       |   true
   2    |       45       |   false
   3    |       31       |   false
   3    |       90       |   true
   3    |       67       |   true
```

In the application, the users basically evaluate if the affirmations are correct or wrong, marking them as true or false. Each affirmation is evaluated only once, so users are evaluating different affirmations.

What I'm trying to do is select a resultset like the one bellow, where I can count the number of affirmations each user marked as correct and the number they marked as false.

```
 user | correct_count | wrong_count
------------------------------------
  1   |      35       |    12
  2   |      76       |    22
  3   |      23       |    41
```

I have a query to count the number of correct answers of each user, and I can simply change the expected value of ísCorrect' field to false, so I'll count the number of wrong answers each user gave. My problem is how to gather the corrcet count and the wrong count, since I can't simply use UNION.

Comment: SUM(iscorrect = 'true')

Comment: is `isCorrect` a boolean or a varchar field?

Comment: why the downvote? it's a legitimate question with clearly stated problem and desired outcome.

Comment: @Quassnoi `isCorrect` is a boolean

Comment: Didn get why the downvote either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  id_user,
        SUM(isCorrect),
        SUM(NOT isCorrect)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        id_user
```

Comment: I had tried the `SUM` before, but missed the `NOT` when I did.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `isCorrect` is being stored as VARCHAR string values `true` and `false`, one way to get the counts is to use a conditional boolean in the SELECT list, and perform use an aggregate function around that.

For example:

```
SELECT t.user
     , SUM(t.isCorrect='true') AS correct_count
     , SUM(t.isCorrect='false') AS wrong_count
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.user
```

If there are values other than `true` or `false`, would those be included in either count? (e.g. `NULL`, `'maybe'`, et al.), or if the datatype of `isCorrect` is other than VARCHAR, the conditional expression would need to be modified appropriately, so that each expression returns `1`'if it's to be included in the count, or `0` if it's not to be included.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I do have boolean values, not varchars, so I accepted @Quassnoi's answer.